# converting csv file to rdf using tarql shows empty results

Tags: csv, web, sparql, rdf, semantics

I m using tarql to convert a csv file to rdf the command runs correctly but i can't find the output (nothing is shown in the windows cmd line and no file is generated)
I m using tarql with windows with the following cmd
C:\tarql-master\target\appassembler\bin\tarql.bat --ntriples xx.rq xx.csv

here is my code

```
    PREFIX dc: <http://dcontology/a#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

CONSTRUCT {
    ?URI owl:class dc:dataset;
    dc:identifier ?identifier;
    dc:title ?title;
    dc:description ?description;
    dc:category ?category;
    dc:keywords ?keywords;
    dc:PublicationDate ?PublicationDate;
    dc:UpdateDate ?UpdateDate;
    dc:frequencyofupdate ?frequencyofupdate;
    dc:Format ?Format;
    dc:License ?license

} 
FROM <file:Metabase.csv> 
WHERE {
  BIND (URI(CONCAT('http://dcontology/dataset/', ?identifier)) AS ?URI)
 BIND (xsd:integer(?identifier) AS ?identifier)
 BIND (xsd:string(?title) AS ?title)
 BIND (xsd:string(?description) AS ?description)
 BIND (xsd:string(?category) AS ?category)
 BIND (xsd:string(?keywords) AS ?keywords)
 BIND (xsd:string(?PublicationDate) AS ?PublicationDate)
 BIND (xsd:string(?UpdateDate) AS ?UpdateDate)
 BIND (xsd:string(?FrequencyOfUpdate) AS ?FrequencyOfUpdate)
BIND (xsd:string(?format) AS ?format)
 BIND (xsd:string(?license) AS ?license)
 
}`
```

and here is the csv file header`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6LfO.png)

Comment: how do you know that `tarql` runs correctly? Also, are you sure the mapping file matches the CSV file correctly? Please show the `tarql` query here and sample CSV data

Comment: @uninformedUser I edited the post you can find the code and CSV header

Comment: tarql runs correctly i dont have any error message

Comment: Your column names start with upper case, but in the SPARQL query you use e.g. `?identifier` - I'm pretty sure that leads to an empty result as `?URI` is never created and thus no triple will be generated. Case-sensitivity matters here I think, try `?Identifier` etc.

Answer (score 0):

#### Case sensitivity

The matching of CSV column names and SPARQL variables is **case-sensitive**.

As you have, for example, "Description" as CSV column name, you need `?Description` in the `WHERE` block of your SPARQL query.

```
PREFIX dc: <http://dcontology/a#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://owlontology/a#> # see bottom of this answer

CONSTRUCT {

  ?URI 

    owl:class dc:dataset ;
    
    dc:identifier           ?identifier_int ;
    dc:title                ?title_str ;
    dc:description          ?description_str ;
    dc:category             ?category_str ;
    dc:keywords             ?keywords_str ;
    dc:PublicationDate      ?publicationDate_str ;
    dc:UpdateDate           ?updateDate_str ;
    dc:frequencyofupdate    ?frequencyOfUpdate_str ;
    dc:Format               ?format_str ;
    dc:License              ?license_str .

} 

#FROM <file:Metabase.csv> 

WHERE {

  BIND ( URI(CONCAT( 'http://dcontology/dataset/', ?Identifier )) AS ?URI ) .

  BIND ( xsd:integer(?Identifier)       AS ?identifier_int ) .
  BIND ( xsd:string(?Title)             AS ?title_str ) .
  BIND ( xsd:string(?Description)       AS ?description_str ) .
  BIND ( xsd:string(?Category)          AS ?category_str ) .
  BIND ( xsd:string(?Keywords)          AS ?keywords_str ) .
  BIND ( xsd:string(?PublicationDate)   AS ?publicationDate_str ) .
  BIND ( xsd:string(?UpdateDate)        AS ?updateDate_str ) .
  BIND ( xsd:string(?FrequencyOfUpdate) AS ?frequencyOfUpdate_str ) .
  BIND ( xsd:string(?Format)            AS ?format_str ) .
  BIND ( xsd:string(?License)           AS ?license_str ) .

}
```

#### Error

If tarql doesn’t find anything to convert (e.g., because the correct column names are not included in the query), it gives no output instead of an error.

Your query, however, should give an error, because you don’t have the `owl` prefix defined:

> Error parsing SPARQL query: Line 5, column 8: Unresolved prefixed name: owl:class

#### Vocabularies

If you meant to use the OWL ontology, note that there is no `owl:class` property defined. If you want to say that the `?URI` entity belongs to a class, you can use the `rdf:type` property (or shorthand: `a`).

`dc` is the common prefix for [DCMI Metadata Terms](http://purl.org/dc/terms/), which doesn’t define `dc:category`, `dc:keywords`, `dc:PublicationDate`, `dc:UpdateDate`, or `dc:frequencyofupdate`.
`dc:Format` and `dc:License` only exist as lowercase variants, and  `dc:dataset` only exists as uppercase variant (by convention, lowercase terms refer to properties, and uppercase terms refer to classes).

In case you don’t use the DCMI Metadata Terms vocabulary, it’s a good practice to use a different prefix than `dc`, because it’s such a well-known vocabulary/prefix.